# Behaviour of i inside the for-loop isn't what I was expecting

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I already solved the problem below using reverse() and push() but I wanted to also solve it using a for..loop just for the sake of my own learning and I'm glad I did because I'm discovering some odd behaviour that I'm hoping somebody can explain and point out to me.

I'm so baffled at the result I'm getting when I return the new array. I'm getting the correct length but it's the values of the new array that's making me scratch my head.  It's as if i is not incrementing on the left-hand side of the assignment statement.

Thanks in advance for your time! : )

Here's the problem

```
// Write a function called unshift which accepts an array and a value and adds the value to the beginning of the array. This function should return the new length of the array.

// Do not use the built in Array.unshift() function!

const arr = [1, 2, 3];
unshift(arr, 0); // return value is 4, the length of the array
// arr; // [0, 1, 2, 3] 

// unshift([4, 5, 6, 7], 10); // return value is 5, the length of 
the array
// arr; // [10,4,5,6,7]
```

I've tried using a temporary variable
    
    `function unshift(arr, val) {
      let currVal
      arr.length = arr.length + 1 // adds an addition position to the 
      array
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) { // my loop condition
        currVal = arr[i] // not behaving as expected
        arr[i + 1] = currVal // value never seems to increment
      }
        arr[0] = val
        return arr // I'm returning the arr rather than its length for 
        now
    }`

This is the solution I thought would work...

```
function unshift(arr, val) {
  arr.length = arr.length + 1 // adds an addition position to the array
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) { // my loop condition
    arr[i + 1] = arr[i] // arr[i] is not behaving as expected
  }
  arr[0] = val
  return arr // I'm returning the arr rather than its length for now
}
```

This is what I'm expecting it to do:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
unshift(arr, 0); // 4
// arr; // [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

But this is what's happening:

```
unshift(arr, 0); // 4
// arr; // [0,1,1,1] // ??? It's as if arr[i] isn't incrementing
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `push` and `reverse`.

```
const unshift = (arr, val) => (arr.reverse(), arr.push(val), arr.reverse()).length;
```

Comment: From the (presumed homework or test) instructions: "This function should return the new length of the array"

Comment: Whoops - fixed @Kaddath.

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite the actual value. If you like to keep the approach, you need to store the last value and assign the value in the loop.

```js
function unshift(arr, val) {
    var item = arr[0];

    arr.length = arr.length + 1;
    for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        [item, arr[i]] = [arr[i], item]; // swap values
    }
    arr[0] = val;
    return arr.length;
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(unshift(arr, 0)); // 4
console.log(arr); // [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

An easier approach is to loop from the end.

```js
function unshift(array, value) {
  var i = array.length;
  
  while (i--) {
    array[i + 1] = array[i];
  }
  array[0] = value;
  return array.length;
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(unshift(arr, 0)); // 4
console.log(arr); // [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Nina, thanks for showing a way to do it by sticking w my approach; the contrast in starting the loop at the end (what's being recommended by the majority) vs the way I was trying to do it it really helped me understand what was happening. I really appreciate your input on this : )

Answer (score 0):

With

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) { // my loop condition
  arr[i + 1] = arr[i] // arr[i] is not behaving as expected
```

you're starting at index 0 and overwriting index `i + 1` with the value at index `i` on every iteration. So, the result is that the array is full of copies of the item originally at index 0 (except for the new value assigned to index 0 at the very end).

Iterate backwards instead, from the array's `.length` down to 0, so you don't lose information due to overwriting:

```js
function unshift(arr, val) {
  for (let i = arr.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
  }
  arr[0] = val;
  return arr.length;
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3];
const newLength = unshift(arr, 0);

console.log(newLength);
console.log(arr);
```

Note that there's no need to assign a new `.length` to the array - assigning to the indicies alone is sufficient.

Comment: Ok, got it! "lose information due to overwriting" this totally makes sense now w the way it's behaving. Thanks for helping me out on this. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for` when ever you have something to do with the items in the array. Make sure not to use it if there is no need to use it. This is because of some performance issues.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
function unshift(arr, val) {
  arr.unshift(val) // add value at the first position of the array
  console.log(arr) // show updated array in the console
  return arr.length // return length of the array
}
unshift(arr, 0)
```